# Caesura before or after "-que"

Tags: caesura

Can a word with the enclitic "-que" still have a caesura before the que? E.g. in the verse:
Arma virumque cano ... is there a caesura between virum and que. Or is there no caesura since the que is part of the word?

Comment: Isn't the caesura in that line after _canō_ (penthemimeral)?